# SharePoint 2010 MySites: How can I disable the ability to create blogs in MySites?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Like the title says, I'm looking for a way to restrict user creation of blogs in MySites.  I've been researching this for the past few days and can't seem to find a good option.

Presently, I'm hiding the links to create a blog through a custom Master page.  I'm using feature stapling to add the custom Master page to MySites which is working; however, not really a 'best practice' since using the URL to create the blog site will still work.

I also don't want to manually change files in the SharePoint root directory structure as it is a poor practice in an upgrade path.

I would appreciate any insight...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're hosting MySites in a separate Web Application, you can use an Event Receiver (derived from [SPWebEventReceiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spwebeventreceiver.aspx) and implementing [WebAdding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spwebeventreceiver.webadding.aspx)) and check that the WebTemplate is `BLOG`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Michael.  I'm working on this now and will let you know how it goes.

Comment: The event receiver is the way to go for sure.